# $_POST['var'] into MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, post, mysqli

I am using WAMP to try and learn a little PHP and SQL. I'm trying to take user input from a very basic table here:

```
<form action="input.php" method="post" class="registration_form"/>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="name">Username :</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="e-mail">E-mail :</label>
      <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="e-mail" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="Password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
     <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
      <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

and I want to be able to take the input and post to a database. I've been trying to make this happen with this code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

//Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 //Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (name, email, password)
VALUES ($_POST[name], $_POST[e-mail], $_POST[password])";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;//
}

$conn->close();
var_dump('name', 'e-mail', 'password');

?>
```

When I try and insert the "" as in $_POST["name"] I get an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\input.php on line 16
```

When I try to remove the "" I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\input.php on line 16
```

I also tried to set the variables in the top of the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
$name=$_POST['name']

//Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 //Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (name, email, password)
VALUES ('name','email', 'password');

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;//
}

$conn->close();
var_dump('name', 'e-mail', 'password');

?>
```

This way I ended up with an error message saying:

```
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$conn' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\input.php on line 9
```

I was able to echo the name in another script using the $_POST, I am not sure why it will not work with the SQL command. If anyone would help out, and/or give me some resources to learn/study from as well I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing ';' after:
$name=$_POST['name']

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please note some points

1) You will get warnings of undefined index because you are not checking about values posted or not. We Should use `isset()` before using values.

2) Second try to use `lowercase` whenever you are giving any name to any tag in php to be sure that no error exist due to typing in `lowercase` or `uppercase`.

3) Try to use `underscore` if your word is long so use `e_mail`;

So you can use this `php` code

```
     <?php

      if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     //Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['e_mail'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests(name, email, password) VALUES('$name','$email','$password')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;//
}

$conn->close();
      }
      ?>
```

I have added name to your `submit` button also changed `e-mail` to `e_mail` and `name="Password"` to `name="password"`

```
<form action="input.php" method="post" class="registration_form"/>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="name">Username :</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="e-mail">E-mail :</label>
      <input type="text" id="e_mail" name="e_mail" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="Password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="Password" name="password" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
     <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
      <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" />
    </div> 
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You are just asking for trouble if you do not sanitise your `$_POST[]` data, the user could really break your DB with that..